# Eclipse + Subclipse: SVN can't open local repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have created initial import of my eclipse project to local file like this:

```
$svn import /home/miso/workspace/DatabaseManager/ file:///home/miso/svn/dbman -m 'Initial import'
```

Now I'd like to add this SVN repository to my Eclipse project (inside Eclipse itself). When I try to add new repository via SVN Reposistory Perspective (it came probably with Subclipse plugin) and navigate to `file:///home/miso/svn/dbman` then I get only this result:

[image]

What did I wrong? Thanks

Comment: What version of Subclipse are you using, and also which version of Subversion?

Comment: SVN: 1.6.12. Subclipse: 1.0.7. I am using also some cvsdude servers where my old subclipse plugin works well with other projects.

Comment: Shouldn't that me a `checkout` instead of an `import`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happens when you use a version of Subclipse that is not compatible with the version of Subversion that created the repository.

This [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/106547/vc/Difference-between-subversion-subclipse) should shed more light on it, basically just make sure your version of Subclipse can interface with whatever version of SVN you created the repository with.

*EDIT* I just did a quick read on Subclipse, my understanding is that any 1.x version of Subclipse should work with any 1.x version of Subversion. However, for 1.6 versions of Subversion you will need the 1.6 version of Subclipse.

**Source:** http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=AE2D434B8F5AC0C0D416B27808DD90BD?pageID=p4wYuA

Comment: Hmm I have different projects versioned on different servers (different SVN). I guess this means, I'd better use terminal :|

Comment: What are the different versions of SVN you are interacting with? If you give us this, maybe there is another tool out there that can interface with a wider range of Subversion versions?

Comment: 1.6 locally and 1.4 @ remote server (I guess, I am not 100% sure what runs on server).

Comment: I did a quick search which turned up squat, however, I'm thinking this might not be a bad type of tool for myself to develop. Doesn't seem like it would be too hard, anyways.

Comment: Read my edit, it seems like you need to upgrade your version of Subclipse to 1.6 to work with 1.6 repositories.

Comment: That's the problem. Newer subclipse doesn't work with that :/ I'll guess I wait for Eclipse Indigo now and will retry then. Thanks for now.

Comment: ...? We are running Subversion 1.6 in house and Subclipse works with my Repository. What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I can confirm that the latest version of Subclipse works with Helios, I use it on the daily. If you're having issues with it, I can try to give you a hand in my spare time if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll wait. I am using 2 eclipses now and I'll be dealing with this issue when I will be forking my work to Indigo release.